# How do i push the value of an input to a state without clearing the state data?

Tags: reactjs

I have this

```
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
```

After I fetch the data from my backend api, I set the state to the response. for example "Hello". so title would be "Hello" at this point.

I have a text area whose value is "title" and onChange I setTitle(e.target.title).

i expect it to append the value gotten from the text area to the  state, but it doesn't work that way.

```
        <textarea
      placeholder="Title"
      type="text"
      value={title}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setTitle(e.target.value);
      }}
    >
      </textarea>
```

Comment: Please try: ``setTitle(prev => `${prev}${e.target.value}`);`` and share your feedback.

Comment: When I do this, it appends, but it does it on change of literally every letter. "Hello" would be added to everything I type. The code works well the way I wrote it, but when I try to save the data added to the state, it saves it as the previous data generated from the api initially. Could you please leave me a link so I could text you directly this one time.

Comment: Your code works!

Comment: for `textarea`, the onChange will give the entire text - so, no need to append. Try like this: `onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}` and share your feedback, please. A working code-snippet has been added to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

useState can get you the previous data and then you can append what you want to it like this.

```
setTitle((prev)=> prev + e.target.value);
```

Comment: When I do this, it appends, but it does it on change of literally every letter. "Hello" would be added to everything I type. The code works well the way I wrote it, but when I try to save the data added to the state, it saves it as the previous data generated from the api initially instead of with the stuff I added to the textarea.

Comment: the wrong would be in the logic of work not in the function. what i understand that the you want to appened text to the work "hello", what you can do is let the it as init value in   const [title, setTitle] = useState("hello"); then use the function useTitle as you where using it at the begining without the prev value.

Answer (score 0):

> You can set the value to the state after fetching the data like this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
 const [state, setState] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
  fetch('http://example.com/songs')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setState(data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
 }, []);
  return (
   <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello textarea</h1>
    <textarea
      value={state}
      onChange={(e) => setState(() => e.target.value)}
                    or
      onChange={e=>setState(e.target.value)}
    />
  </div>
 );
}
```